# Iphone CSS issue for mobile view only

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Unable to detect css in mobile view for iphone in real device, it works fine in browser responsive test emulator for mobile view, it also looks better in android phones but not in iphone device

[image: this is output of responsive tabs]

Comment: can you give a better description of your problem

Comment: @nusje2000 i put image of both displays i.e androis and IOS

Answer (score 2):

To have a responsive bootstrap on mobile devices, ensure you have the `<meta>` viewport tag in your `<head>` :

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

[Explanation here](https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/articles/quick-tip-dont-forget-the-viewport-meta-tag--webdesign-5972)

Comment: i upload image please have a look

Answer (score 0):

```
 html 
 {
     background: url(your image source)
     no-repeat 
     center center fixed;
     background-size: cover;
     height: 100%;
     overflow: hidden;
 }
 body
 {
      height:100%;
      overflow: scroll;
      -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
 }
```

Reference :https://css-tricks.com/forums/topic/full-page-backgrounds-on-ios-background-size-cover/page/2/

Comment: there is no background, the tabs dissappeared in ios mobile view